# MongoDB : How to search based on two Parameters in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a Collection named as Orders in my Mongo DB .

Is it possible to do a  search on mongo DB based on two fileds .

For example i want to search the collection based on symbol and hi

```
db.Orders.find({"symbol" : "AADI"})
```

Please let me know how can i include the other parameter hi  also in the search ??

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just have two conditions separated by commas:

e.g.

```
db.users.find(
    { status: "A",
      age: 50 }
)
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Answer (score 2):

Mongodb provides an implicit `AND` , so when you do

```
db.inventory.find( { price: 1.99, qty: { $lt: 20 } , sale: true } )
```

it is same as

```
db.inventory.find({ $and: [ { price: 1.99 }, { qty: { $lt: 20 } }, { sale: true } ] } )
```

For other operators you can have a look at the [reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/)

**mixing $or with logical AND**

```
db.inventory.find( { price:1.99, $or: [ { qty: { $lt: 20 } }, { sale: true } ] } )
```

This query will select all documents in the inventory collection where:

the price field value equals 1.99 and
either the qty field value is less than 20 or the sale field value is true.

**Other operators**

You can refer to the [reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/) for examples to other operators.

Answer (score 0):

Also, once you use:

```
db.users.find(
{ status: "A",
  age: 50 }).pretty()
```

Using `pretty()` method at the end of the statement, you make sure that the info comes with a `\n` per `key : value`